# How to check for empty values in an array and return the key with empty value?

Tags: php, arrays

How to I check if all the keys in an array has values. ANd if it doesnot have any values how to print that key.

```
$value = array(
        [title] => Test Name Four
        [first_name] => 
        [last_name] => M
        [field_company] => ABC
        [email] => 
        [client_phone_number] => 
        [address_line_1] => 
        [address_line_2] => Address 3
        [address_line_3] => 
        [address_line_4] => 
        [post_code] => 
        )
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is_null` for this.

```
$array = array('something' => 0, 'other' => false, 'foo' => null);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (is_null($val)) {
        echo $key . " is null!\r\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$emptyKeys = array();    
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($v) {
        $emptyKeys[$k] = $k;
    }
}
print_r($emptyKeys);
```

Comment: foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if (empty($value))
        echo "$key empty <br/>";
    else
        echo "$key not empty <br/>";
}